# Ubuntu 16.04 screen tearing with multiple monitors (one portrait)

Tags: multiple-monitors, tearing

I have two Dell monitors (same model). Both have a resolution of `1920x1080`. When I connect the second monitor everything is fine.

When I switch the secondary monitor to portrait mode, the main monitor starts tearing when scrolling and moving windows around.

What could be causing this and how could I fix this?

I use Nvidia drivers and GTX960 GPU and both monitors are connected to the same GPU.

Answer (score 0):

First install CompizConfig-Settings-Manager by

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

Open CompizConfig-Settings-Manager find `Composite` and `check` it. Now Click `Composite` and `uncheck` the box of `Unredirect Fullscreen Windows`.
Close CompizConfig-Settings-Manager.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers to multiple questions.  If the question you took this answer from and the question here being asked are identical or similar enough that they are the same problem, consider flagging this question here as a duplicate of the other one.